# what is the reason behind chrome not implementing this feature?

Tags: browser

Many browsers implement "Do you want to close all tabs" dialog box when we try to close the browser but not chrome.

Why is this? What's the reason behind chrome not implementing such feature?

Does it affect UX here?

Answer (score 1):

On this site, you'd only get speculation.You'd have to find the google blog post on that one.

My best guess is that it's not necessary.

When you open chrome it loads all the tabs which were already there from when you closed it. Because it saves the state, asking the user regarding closing all tabs is unnecessary because (maybe based on their research)  most people would prefer to resume than start fresh.

Imho-other browsers may not do this and will opt to start fresh just to launch faster.

Comment: "When you open chrome it loads..." Only if you tell it to. Mine doesn't... Or maybe it does by default and I told it not to :)

Comment: Firefox also has an option to restore last browsing session..

Comment: "When you open chrome it *can* load..." therefore it becomes unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Chrome Settings]

Chrome offers the options to 'Continue where you left off'. I do however question how often people do use this.

Chrome also has the option to open recently closed tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't prefer dialog boxes.

I use the same keyboard shortcut used to restore closed tabs and the entire Window + all tabs came back:

PC: `CTRL + SHIFT + T`

MAC: `COMMAND + SHIFT + T`

[Window Close Protector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-close-protector/lnpifgapnmpninomacbhdlconlpikdai) is a Chrome browser extension that adds a warning dialog to help protect against accidentally closing multiple tabs.

On MAC and using the latest version of chrome, just select this:

[image]

When you turn off your computer and come back without closing chrome, chrome asks you to restore the last session.

Answer (score 0):

There is a selection in the menu to exit the browser which is what you are wanting to do. Otherwise, most people don't want to close all their tabs at once most of the time. Nowadays, people use their computer mostly to surf the web. To close all their tabs at once would be unusual and, perhaps, disastrous. Fortunately, most browsers, if not all, can recall all your tabs when you restart them.

Comment: You make a lot of assumptions here. "*most people don't want to close all their tabs at once*" and "*Nowadays, people use their computer mostly to surf the web*". I don't know if these are true. For instance, what about people who use the web for work (email, cloud documents, project-management tools...)? The browser is used for far more than just browsing websites these days.

Comment: @JonW No assumptions at all. I guarantee it's true. It's my job to know this stuff. Note I'm not saying no one does that. That's what the exit selection is for but, yes, if it weren't for the web and games, hardly anyone would own a computer today.